# Why registering user with fortify I got invalid user type?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-fortify

In Laravel 8 app with inertiajs/vuejs2/fortify I try to run user register method wih axios
request(I need to make register wih confirmation code) from vue component :

```
makeRegisterStep1() {
    console.log('makeRegisterStep1 this.registerForm::')
    console.log(this.registerForm)

    Window.axios.post('/register', this.registerForm)
        .then(resp => {
            console.log('makeRegisterStep1 resp::')
            console.log(resp)
            ...  
        })
        .catch(
            function (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        )
},   // makeRegisterStep1() {
```

bUT i GOT ERROR

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

AND i SEE IN LOG FILE :

```
[2021-12-28 10:18:51] local.ERROR: Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController::store(): Argument #2 ($creator) must be of type Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers, App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser given, called in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Laravel\\Fortify\\Http\\Controllers\\RegisteredUserController::store(): Argument #2 ($creator) must be of type Laravel\\Fortify\\Contracts\\CreatesNewUsers, App\\Actions\\Fortify\\CreateNewUser given, called in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers/RegisteredUserController.php:51)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): Laravel\\Fortify\\Http\\Controllers\\RegisteredUserController->store()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/photographers/li/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(262): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()

I modified app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php, but not Create user part :

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {

        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            return view('auth.login', [] );
        });

        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            $request = request();

            if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                if ( $user->status === 'A') {
                    return $user;
                }
                else {
                    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                        Fortify::username() => __("Your account is inactive"),
                    ]);
                }

            }
        });

        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            return view('auth.register', [] );
        });

        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
}
```

hOW IT CAN BE FIXED ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
No the pipeline is default,
and checking routes I see :

```
php artisan route:list 

             | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified   |
|        | GET|HEAD      | register                                    | register                        | Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController@create                  | web                                                |
|        |               |                                             |                                 |                                                                                   | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated:web    |
|        | POST          | register                                    | generated::qWOIdxP9ML8fo3yR     | Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController@store                   | web                                                |
|        |               |                                             |                                 |                                                                                   | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated:web    |
|        | GET|HEAD      | test                                        | test                            | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@test                                          | web                                                |
|        | DELETE        | user                                        | current-user.destroy            | Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Inertia\CurrentUserController@destroy          | web                                                |
|        |               |                                             |                                 |                                                                                   | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                   |
|        |               |                                             |                                 |                                                                                   | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified   |
|        | GET|HEAD      | user/confirm-password                       | password.confirm                | Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ConfirmablePasswordController@show
```

Header of app/Models/User.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasPermissions;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class User extends Authenticatable  implements HasMedia //, MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasRoles;
    use HasPermissions;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    protected $fillable
        = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'status',
            'password'
        ];
```

Originally that was laravel 8 admin starter kit based on bootstrap/jquery, without Fortify/Jetstream.
I installed Fortify manually with login service I need.

Also I use CreateNewUser class in my users seeder : :

```
app(CreateNewUser::class)->create([
    'id'         => 1,
    'name'       => 'Admin',
    'email'      => 'admin@site.com',
    'password'   => '11111111',
    'status'     => 'A',
], true, [PERMISSION_APP_ADMIN]);
```

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Code here looks ok, your `/register` does hit the Fortify inbuilt controllers, right? Or did you change the pipeline?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Seems ok again, could you also post the `fortify.php` file contents (mainly the features array)?

Comment: 'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
//        Features::resetPasswords(),
//        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
/*        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),*/
    ],

Comment: I compared your code to every line with a newly created one, and everything matches except the 'name' for `/register` in your `route:list`. Mine gives a blank, yours is `generated::qWOIdxP9ML8fo3yR `. So either that, or somehow your fortify installation seems to be corrupted.

Comment: Any adea how can i be fixed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240500/discussion-between-siddharth-bhansali-and-mstdmstd).